# ElasticSearch scoring parent documents by child field with default values

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Let's say I have some parent documents named "room", and some child documents named "person" with "age" field. Now I want to score some rooms using the age field using custom_score query in ES.

I have already make the query work almost as expected, the only issue is: the empty rooms(with no child documents) are not scored. How can I give them a default score or something. In this example, I want to score five rooms with room_id 1~5. If room 4 has no child documents, it won't be scored. The query will only hit 4 records with expected scores. What I want is giving the empty room a default score. Maybe function score query is suitable for this case, but I'm using NEST as the .NET client which currently doesn't support function score query.

BTW: CSS of SO is not working here, I don't know why. If this post is not well-formatted, please help to edit, thanks.

```
{
  "query": {
    "custom_score": {
      "script": "_score",
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": {
            "has_child": {
              "type": "person",
              "score_type": "sum",
              "query": {
                "custom_score": {
                  "script": "doc['person.age'].value - 50d",
                  "query": {
                    "match_all": {}
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "room_id": [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `has_child` filter makes it include only the parent records that have a child, but you want all the parent records.  You can use a bool should query with two should clauses:

- records that have a child (`must` with `has_child` and `custom_score` calculation)
- records that don't have a child (`must_not` with `has_child` and default score)

```
{
  "query": {
    "custom_score": {
      "script": "_score",
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": {
            "bool" : {
              "should" : [
                {
                  "bool" : {
                    "must" : {
                      "has_child": {
                        "type": "person",
                        "score_type": "sum",
                        "query": {
                          "custom_score": {
                            "script": "doc['person.age'].value - 50d",
                            "query": {
                              "match_all": {}
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "bool" : { 
                    "must_not" : {
                      "has_child": {
                        "type": "person",
                        "query": {
                          "match_all": {}
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "room_id": ["1","2","3","4","5"]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```